# Formatting Menu for Edittext in Android

Tags: android, android-edittext

I trying to create a note apps that have an ability to format the selected text in EditText like the one I usually use in Onenote. But everytime I click my menu icon, the selected text in EditText is resetted and the menu is closed itself.

This is my code in my custom Edit Text

```
 public void init()
{
    this.setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback(new ActionMode.Callback() {
        @Override
        public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            MenuInflater inflater = mode.getMenuInflater();
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.edit_text_menu, menu);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {

        }
    });
}
```

Menu Layout

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/action_bold"
        android:title="Bold"/>
    <item android:id="@+id/action_underline"
        android:title="Underline"/>
    <item android:id="@+id/action_italic"
        android:title="Italic"/>
</menu>
```

the screenshot of onenote menu
http://i57.tinypic.com/zlriu9.png

and screenshot of my apps
http://i58.tinypic.com/2yjwlys.jpg

What is the right way to **make a menu** for **EditText** to format just the selected text?

**Update! Already found a solution that I think work this far**

I just need to override the onWindowFocusChanged function, so when I click another menu, it won't lose its selection.

Comment: have u tried onOptionsItemSelected() method for open your overflow menu?

Comment: Sorry, but I can't found it in EditText class. Only in the MainActivity, but thanks anyway. When I try it I found an answer that I think is good enough :)